# Creating linkedlist of generic datatype, but all nodes should be of same datatype in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I want to create the LinkedList of objects, but I also want to make sure that all the nodes in LinkedList should be of same datatype. This datatype should be decided at runtime. i.e. if user creates first node with datatype string, all other datatype should be string.

```
class Node{
    Object data;
    Node next;
}
```

So, if I create the first node with datatype string, then all other nodes should be of datatype string.

Comment: You mean at compile time.

Comment: This could be at runtime. I am planning to keep my class Generic, but I want to make sure that whatever nodes get added to list after first node, it should be of same datatype as of first node.

Comment: Yes, that's what compile-time generics is for. You can't put a `String` or a `Node<String>` on a `Node<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use one static boolean and Object class variable and generic like;

```
private class Node<E> {
          private E data;
          private static Object check = null;
          private static boolean first = true;

          public Node(Node<E> prev, Node<E> next , E element){ // your parameters can change with list type

                if(first){
                      check = (E) element ;
                      first = false;
                 }
                 if ( element.getClass() == check.getClass()){ // checking classes
                       Node<E> node ... // create node
                  }
                 else{
                        throw new Exception(“Type missmatch”);
                 }
          }
   // other methods
```

Boolean variable check that is this first node and Object variable check that are new nodes type same with first one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built in way to do this in Java. Generics, e.g. `List<String>`, are compile time only.

If you want to have these types of checks, you will have to create a custom list that checks these constraints whenever new items are added to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can keep a variable in your class and whenever you insert the first element, set the variable to the type of the object being inserted. For an insert operation, check the type of object to be inserted with the variable and insert it only if it matches!
Hope that helps!